# Exception:'Field "label” does not exist Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to apply the KNN algorithm. I have two columns: `id` and `features`

```
> KNN.printSchema
root
|-- id: int (nullable = true)
|-- features: double (nullable = true)
```

Split my data into training and test

```
  val training = spark.read.parquet("/usr/local/spark/dataset/data/user")
  val df = training.map(r => (Vectors.dense(r.getAs[Seq[Double]]("features").toArray),r.getAs[Integer]("id"))).toDF("features","id")
  val assembler = new VectorAssembler().setInputCols(Array("id","features")).setOutputCol("feature")
  val data = assembler.transform(df)
  val splits = df.randomSplit(Array(0.8, 0.2), seed = 1234L) 
  val (trainingData, testData) = (splits(0), splits(1))
```

And building  model

```
 val knnModel = knn.fit(trainingData)
 val predicted = knnModel.transform(testData)
 predicted.show()
```

But that causes this error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field "label" does not exist.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This classifier is expecting a "label" column in your dataframe. In Spark ML estimators normally the "label" field is the default name for them to perform the optimization process

Comment: please,can you explain with code?

Comment: please ask a question with reproducible data. In this case you can provide the schema and sample of your dataframe.

Comment: @salmaR , which knnModel are you using? I mean from which library? AFAIK there are no KNN models avaialble in spark ml library

Comment: Can you post your dataframe schema?

Comment: @Remis Haroon I add  libraryDependencies += "com.github.saurfang.spark-knn" % "spark-knn-examples_2.11" % "0.3.0" in sbt and then add spark-knn-0.2.0.jar.

Comment: ok,I add schema in question @EmiCareOfCell44

Answer (score 2):

You can take as reference the example implementation available in the examples dir. I suppose you are using the knn implementation:  https://github.com/saurfang/spark-knn.

As I said in my comment you must create a dataset with a label column in order to start your knn optimization:

```
 val rawDataset = MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile(sc, "data/mnist/mnist.bz2")
  .toDF()
```

This reads the file and creates a dataframe with labeled training samples. Try this one and extract the generated schema, you will see a label column. In your schema you don´t have any, only the features column. As this algorithm, unlike the K-means, is a **supervised** algorithm you must provide the label column for **each dataframe row**.

Comment: thanks for your reply @EmiCareOfCell44 .but I want build model for knn to know predicted values.